# Conda cannot access Bioconda channel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install packages in my anaconda3 environment using `conda install -c <channel-name> <package-name>` and only `conda install <package-name>` too but it fails everytime. 
The error I receive is :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: bioconda
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

I have added bioconda, conda-forge and defaults as channels in conda config. I am getting this error no matter what package, and I know for sure the packages are present in the anaconda website under the given channel!

`conda config --show channels` gives me

```
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
```

and

`conda config --show-sources`
gives me

```
ssl_verify: False
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
```

Could anyone help in this please!

Comment: I'm not sure what your conda version is. But [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8612) may help.

Comment: Likely temporary failure, bioconda is working for me. BTW, your channels are not set according to recommendations from conda-forge/bioconda, `defaults` should come last.

Comment: @FabienP I did try with the list as recommended from conda-forge/bioconda. But it still gives same error

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Is your machine offline? Can you visit the web address (i.e., `https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda`)?

Comment: @merv yes the site is working fine